# Loading a large of amounts of strings into my ArrayList, I dont want to clog up my class

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I have a ArrayList and I want to put a lot of strings into it (several hundred) but I don't want to code around a huge list of .add()'s and such. Can I important the strings from my strings.xml file into the ArrayList? If so, how?

Comment: What's wrong with using .add()? Perhaps a code example would help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using .add() technically. It does everything I want. But there's a draw back. I want to add several hundred words and I would have a huge list to deal with. And If I'm still adding or adjusting code I don't want to have to scroll up and down a few hundred lines of .add()'s in order to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling up and down an ArrayList?  I don't see the problem with adding 100Ks of words to a list.

Comment: What I mean by scrolling is I have to type them out one by one right? That means I have hundreds of lines of added words. If I have any other code above or below it all those hundreds of lines, I have to scroll up and down the code window really far. This is more about code readability. If I call in the words from another file, I don't have to deal with looking at them. I guess I might not have been clear before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the values saved in strings.xml file you can simply do this:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(values, getResources.getStringArray(R.array.words));
```

or

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(getResources.getStringArray(R.array.words));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of reading  the "words.txt"file from the assets-direcytory in your project. Each word on a line by itself.

```
    /*
     *  If you know the number of words at compile time, 
     * specify it here in the initial capacity
     */
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(50);  
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("words.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            words.add(line);
        }

        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the 100's of strings into a file and read from it. Iterate using a for loop to add these strings in. If you do not want to use a file, user String[] words = new String[]{"test","me"..."last word"} and then iterate over it.

Comment: If my strings are in a StringArray (in my strings.xml) and I create an ArrayList<String>, I can run the StringArray through a For Each loop and be good right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have thousands of words, probably putting them into a txt file is a good solution. However, if the number of words are not that much you can do one more thing to avoid calling add() multiple times:

String[] myArray = {"stack", "oveflow", "java", "array",...}; //large array with lot of Strings.

List list = Arrays.asList(myArray);

Answer (score 0):

If the xml file is in some specific format you can also easily read them all using dom4j

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Address studentId="1001">
        <Details name="Sam" age="" sex="M" class="10" />
    </Address>
    <Address studentId="1002">
        <Details name="Krish" age="" sex="M" class="10" />
    </Address>
</Root>
```

you can read with this code:

```
String xmlFileName = "D:/validation/validator/src/summa/sample.xml";
  String xPath = "//Root/Address";
  Document document = getDocument( xmlFileName );
  List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes( xPath );
  for (Node node : nodes)
  {
     String studentId = node.valueOf( "@studentId" );
     stringArray.add( studentId );
  }
```

Comment: if that is the only use, I agree... but usually when you start with xml you'll finish to use it in a lot of places.
moreover dom4j is quite lightweight...